# how to show 4 different videos inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, video

I want to show 4 different animations inside `UIScrollView` in one time, all of them has 200+ frames, so I think that the best solution to solve this is to show videos. It costs less memory then animations. My videos are ~ 500x300 dimensions, and I want to show them as 250x150. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

this must be the solution of your problem

```
 - (void)layoutScrollImages
{
UIView *view = nil;
NSArray *subviews = [self.scrollView subviews];

// reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
for (view in subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] && view.tag > 0)
    {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
        view.frame = frame;

        curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
    }
}

// set the content size so it can be scrollable
//[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((numImages * kScrollObjWidth),    [self.scrollView bounds].size.height)];

[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((numImages * kScrollObjWidth), kScrollObjHeight)];

}
```